# What is Error "The permission was revoked"

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have a some code like this for get user location getLocaiton is a onclick listener:

```
function getLocation() {

if (navigator.geolocation) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setLocation, errorLocation);

   } else {
alert('error')
}
}
 let errorLocation = (error) => {
    console.log(error)
}
let setLocation = (location) => {
 try {
   console.log('ok')
   console.log(location.coords)
    } catch (e) {

    }
    }
```

and i get this Error `The permission was revoked` in errorLocation() function

Answer (score 1):

You are probably facing a [`PERMISSION_DENIED`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationPositionError) error because you denied location access.

> The acquisition of the geolocation information failed because the page didn't have the necessary permissions, for example because it is blocked by a [Permissions Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Permissions_Policy)

Try enabling it:

[image: Site permissions]

Comment: I Check that and every things is ok But i still get this error

Comment: It's better to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or at least paste more info about the error, like the stack trace or a screenshot of it.