# Permission was revoked while the location permission is allowed

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have an anchor element, when the user clicks it, it will trigger the geolocation API. I have set the location permission to allowed. But I still get the error message: "Permission was revoked."

```
askLocation.addEventListener("click", () => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        const pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
        };
        console.log(pos);
      },
      (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        console.log("error");
      }
    );
  } else {
    console.log("cannot access your location");
  }
});
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76959337/what-is-error-the-permission-was-revoked.

Comment: Before making the geolocation request, you can check the permission status using the Permissions API. This allows you to understand the current state of permissions.